# Why does CoroutineScope exist?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As far as design reasoning goes, why did the authors of Kotlin's coroutine library decide to create `CoroutineScope`? As far as I can tell, it really only serves as a receiver for coroutine builders that holds a `CoroutineContext`, as well as some pass through functions to that context's elements. Even a scope's cancellation is just a passthrough call to the context's job.

Did the authors just want to reserve the right to add more things to a scope later? Can't the current iteration of coroutines effectively just cut the scope out and make a `CoroutineContext` both the receiver and the container for a simpler design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roman Elizarov himself (lead of the coroutines library dev team at the time) described in [his article](https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055), the difference is their intended purpose.

They effectively contain the same stuff, but they are used in different ways, and giving such interfaces different names allowed to manipulate them more easily and in particular define function signatures more clearly.

Comment: oh that's interesting reasoning. I wonder why they ended up exposing cancellation through `CoroutineContext.cancel`, `CoroutineContext.Job.cancel`, AND `CoroutineScope.cancel`. There are other weird things like this that kind of fly in the face of the "different uses" viewpoint where the lines are heavily blurred.

Comment: The job's `cancel()` makes sense, because that's ultimately the primitive for managing coroutine lifecycles and cancelling them. The coroutine scope's  `cancel()` makes sense because that's the abstraction for structured concurrency, which is technically backed by a job - only `GlobalScope` breaks this invariant but it is explicitly marked as delicate, so I guess the user is supposed to understand that when using it. I agree about the `CoroutineContext`'s one. I am not quite sure why this one would be used, as it doesn't seem semantically correct. I guess it's like a low-level helper